# How to change the git directory delimiter?

Tags: windows, git, command-line-interface

When working inside a windows command prompt, all of my paths indicate director separators with a backslash `\`, when using GIT commands, all of the paths are instead using forwardslash `/`. How do I change GIT's output to mirror my command line output?

Example inconsistent directory indicators;

```
D:\git\demo>git status --s
A  test/subdir/foo.txt
```

Comment: Adding the tools within git\usr\bin to my path and using them from the command line is a work around, but I still run into problems when I attempt to copy paths from the command line into other windows application's open file dialog.

Comment: Why do you need to change it? git bash is unix while cmd is windows.

Comment: windows commands such as erase or rmdir do not work with '/' delimited file paths

Comment: - I want to use the windows command line

Comment: Most Windows commands are quite okay with slash-delimited paths, just as long as they don't *begin* with a slash. The underlying APIs are fully compatible with forward slashes. I recommend using forward slashes, and then seeking help the other way ("Such-and-such can't use file names like test/subdir/foo.txt - how can I work around this?"). Otherwise you're going to spend all your time fighting against git and bash.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I change GIT's output to mirror my command line output?

First, all git commands are executed in a `git bash` sub-shell, which explains why you see '`/`'.
A '`\`' is an escape character for a bash session, which is why it is not used in any bash command output.

You would need to use a git wrapper (a git.pat set in your PATH) in order to replace any `/` by `\`.

`git.bat`:

```
C:\prgs\git\latest\bin\git.exe %*|C:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\sed.exe -e 's:/:\\\\:'
```

Make sure `git.bat` is set *before* `git.exe` in your `%PATH%`: type `where git` to check the order in which git(s) are discovered.
And replace `C:\prgs\git\latest` by the path your Git is installed.

By specifying the full path for `git.exe` and for `sed.exe`, you are sure to use the right executable.

Comment: Just to nitpick, I don't believe git runs everything in bash -- it's just that git.exe is built against mingw.

Comment: Coloration is lost, and since it is just a regex, it matches any `/` in the output on non-path elements :(

Comment: @PeterNied Yes, it is a workaround: Git remains at its core a Linux tool.

Comment: @PeterNied Do you have a specific issue which would require for you to get Git output with \ instead of /?

Comment: @VonC windows commands such as erase or rmdir do not work with '/' delimited file paths, which I would like to be taking from the ouput of git log --stat or git status

Comment: @PeterNied Then I would advise to put first in your `PATH` the `<Git\>usr\bin` folder: it include `rm` (or `rm -Rf` which does work nicely with Unix-style paths. Plus, even in a regular CMD session, a `git-xxx` script will be executed in a git bash session when called as `git xxx`. Ie, you can execute bash scripts from your CMD shell.

Comment: @VonC, thanks for attempting to answer my question, it sounds like git just doesn't have this level of flexibility, and if I want to workaround the issue, I am going to be creating more alternative problems for myself.  - I might see if I can submit a PR to add this flexibility for full stack windows users that like the git command line

Comment: @PeterNied I agree, but again, you can use bash script.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you're looking for seems to be not specifically "how do I make Git use `\` in file paths" but rather "how do I make Git generate file paths with `\`", you can pipe the output through `sed` (which is packaged in Git Bash) like so:

```
$ git status --s | sed 's/\//\\/g'
 M dir\file.py
?? dir\input001.txt
?? dir\output001.txt
```

and to avoid typing `sed` every single time you can configure a Git alias to do it for you:

```
[alias]
    ws = "!ws() { : git status ; git status --short $@ | sed 's/\\//\\\\/g' ; } && ws"
```

which will let you do this:

```
$ git ws
 M dir\file.py
?? dir\input001.txt
?? dir\output001.txt
```